# Are iPhone sim cards locked specifically to the iPhone hardware?

Tags: iphone, sim

I've got an iPhone 3GS, on the UK network of O2

Can I take that sim card out, and put it into another mobile device (not iPhone) ? I don't have a spare device to try this hence asking here

More importantly, would the sim card actually work in a non-iPhone device or is it locked for iPhone usage only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No SIM card is locked to any phone. The SIM card will work in any unlocked device supporting the frequencies used by the carrier that issued the SIM card.

Comment: As far as I know, it’s not **possible** to lock it to a phone.

Comment: Well when I bought the phone, the SIM card packaging stated it would only work in the iPhone

Comment: The SIM isn't iPhone-only. For an example of using it elsewhere, check out this TUAW article, [How To: Use iPhone 4 data plan with iPad 3G](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/09/how-to-use-iphone-4-data-plan-with-ipad-3g/print/)

Comment: The iPhone SIM can be used in any unlocked phone, but there are some companies (Tracfone) that lock their SIMs to their hardware.